# Sometimes classes not get woven during load time weaving

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, aspectj

I have some classes marked with @Configurable annotation with @Autowired fields and some of them works fine but other throw NullPointerException due to fields not getting @Autowired correctly.

My configuration is like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = true)
@Import({
    ...
})
@ComponentScan(
    basePackageClasses = {
        ...
    }
)
public class RootConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
```

aop.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="aero.geoscan..*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring may load weaver bean lately and thus not process all neccessary classes.
Try to add `@DependsOn("loadTimeWeaver")` to your @Configuration.

And if it doesn't help add `<weaver options="-verbose -debug -showWeaveInfo">` to your aop.xml. It will help to resolve problem by providing additional logs